# IDENTITY_INSERT ON not being respected for Entity Framework DBSet.Add method

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I run this query:

```
context.Database.SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Songs] ON;");
```

just before I do the `.Add()` method from a `DbSet`.

My data still is using the identity value instead of the ID that I'm supplying.

I only want this temporarily (for data migration) and then it should remain auto generated identity in the future.

I'm using SQL Server CE 4 for my database.

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086006/how-can-i-force-entity-framework-to-insert-identity-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF can't guess that you've executed an IDENTITY_SET command and change its internal logic accordingly.

If you need to insert specific Id values, use SqlCommand for the inserts too.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I had to use SqlCeCommand. I wanted to keep my code agnostic of the database, but I guess I can't.

Comment: Well, SET IDENTITY_INSERT isn't particularly db-agnostic anyway :-)

Answer (score 4):

This can be a problem. `DbContext` handles db connection itself. This works only if inserts are executed on the same connection as turning on identity insert. I think it releases the connection after this command. You can try to use different DbContext's constructor and pass your own opened `DbConnection` instance and handle its closing by yourselves.